# Coherence and non-linear interactions

Tags: non-linear, coherence

Reportedly, coherence-based metrics are primarily influenced by linearity in phase. However, [Klein et al](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.332.1738) report that coherence is also:

> ... very  sensitive  to fluctuations  of  linearity  in phase, relatively less so to nonlinear fluctuations of amplitude and completely insensitive to linear fluctuations in amplitude. How much both types of linearity contribute to the final measure, however, remains somewhat unclear and, therefore, some authors have argued that amplitude should not contribute to the final measure at all, using a "phase locking value"[9] instead,which is essentially the square root of (4) with all the moduli set to 1

without citing papers that prove the sensitivity of coherence with non-linear amplitude fluctuations.

Does this stand and if yes, are there any papers supporting it?

Comment: I have edited your question to improve its clarity. I think that the passage from the paper is clear enough on its meaning (?). If I have misinterpreted the passage you were referring to please go ahead and correct it.

Comment: Thanks editing. Sure, I probably have not put this correctly -my question ultimately is about proving the sensitivity of coherence to non-linear amplitude fluctuations. Updated the question accordingly. ta